# How can I fix "Error: Formulae found in multiple taps"?

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, phpredis

I want to install php54-redis.

> Yu:nginx Yu$ brew install josegonzalez/php/php54-redis
>
> ==> Installing php54-redis from josegonzalez/homebrew-php
>
> Error: Formulae found in multiple taps:
>
> - homebrew/php/php54
> - josegonzalez/php/php54
>
> Please use the fully-qualified name e.g. homebrew/php/php54 to refer the formula.

What am I doing wrong and how is thise done properly?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
brew untap josegonzalez/homebrew-php
```

[This](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/40776) is same problem.

`josegonzalez/homebrew-php` has been  moved to `homebrew/php`, so we can untap it to fix error.

Comment: If this is actually an answer, please detail with what was an error and how does this helps.

Answer (score 44):

Referencing [this GitHub issue link](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/1775), you need to do the following with the tap that you don't want.  In this case, if you don't want the `homebrew/php/php54` tap, try this:

```
brew untap homebrew/php
brew tap --repair
brew update
```

I just tried it in on the other tap (`brew untap josegonzalez/php`) and it worked well.

Comment: I also had to brew unlink php53 to get php54 to install. The above was very helpful. Thank you!!

Comment: @user24793 My pleasure! Glad my little contribution helped someone out in the SO universe :)

Answer (score 1):

Took me forever but I figured it out. I kept on getting the same errors:

`brew upgrade ==> Language Matters Warning: The Cloud Native Buildpacks project is updating its language in an Warning: effort to be more inclusive. Part of that effort includes renaming our Warning: default git branches from 'master' to 'main'. Warning:  Error: To upgrade pack, retap it with:`

```
# untap old repo (if present)
brew untap buildpack/tap

# untap current repo (if present)
brew untap buildpacks/tap

# retap current repo
brew tap buildpacks/tap

# upgrade
brew upgrade pack`
```

What I ended up doing was going to the `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps` folder and deleting the `buildpack` folder.